# How to prove there exists an isometry mapping all but the first two coordinates of $x, y$ and $z$ to zero

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry, metric-spaces, systems-of-equations

> For any $x, y, z\in\mathbb R^n(n>2)$, there exists an isometry mapping all but the first two coordinates of $x, y$ and $z$ to zero.

How to prove the statement above? I know that translation and rotation are isometries, but I’m just wondering if we can formulate a strict proof.

I tried in the following way but got stuck.

Let $L_{*\star}$ be the distance between $*$ and $\star$ and let $(x_1’,x_2’,0,\ldots,0), (y_1’,y_2’,0,\ldots,0), (z_1’,z_2’,0,\ldots,0)$ be the corresponding points. Since it is a distance-preserving mapping, we have

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
L_{xy}=\sqrt{(x_1’-y_1’)^2+(x_2’-y_2’)^2}\\
L_{xz}=\sqrt{(x_1’-z_1’)^2+(x_2’-z_2’)^2}\\
L_{yz}=\sqrt{(y_1’-z_1’)^2+(y_2’-z_2’)^2}
\end{array}\right.$$

I got stuck when trying to prove that system of equations has at least one solution. I suspect I’m doing it in the wrong way. Could you give me some help? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Translation and rotation are isometries.

Comment: @Dunham Yes, I know that. I’m just wondering if we can formulate a strict proof. Thanks you.

Comment: Take the plane defined by the 3 points and move it to the plane spanned by the first two standard basis vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given points $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}^n$, we can define an isometry $M:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ by $M(w) = T(w-z)$ where $T$ is an orthogonal matrix.

**General idea**

Consider the $n\times 2$ matrix with column vectors $x-z$, $y-z$.  Apply rotators or reflectors as in QR decomposition to construct the matrix $T$.

**Example**

Let $x=[2,3,3,1]^\top$, $y=[2,3,5,2]^\top$, $z=[1,1,1,1]^\top$

Initially we form the matrix

\begin{equation}
[x-z \ y-z]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1\\
2 & 2\\
2 & 4\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{equation}

The QR decomposition of this matrix is (numerically with floating point precision)

\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
-0.3333333 &  -0.24759378&  -0.89364759& -0.17023569\\
-0.66666667 & -0.49518757 &  0.29595756 &  0.47196817\\
-0.66666667&  0.61898446 &  0.15086624& -0.38685032\\
-0.        &  0.55708601& -0.30173248 &  0.77370064
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
-3.        & -4.33333333\\
 0.        &  1.79505494 \\
 0.        &  0.        \\
 0.        &  0.       
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{equation}

Let $T$ be the transpose of the matrix $Q$ which is orthogonal. Then $M$ will map $x$ to the first column of $R$, $y$ to the second column of $R$, and $z$ to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I don’t quite get it. If we need to apply QR decomposition, then what’s the matrix that we decompose? $[x-z~y-z~0]$? Why? I’d be grateful if you could add more details in your answer.

Comment: I added some details and changed notation to clarify.  Previously I was using  $L$ as the isometry, but it may have been confusing due to the use of $L$ in the example.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve got it!